# Fibreboard in Chimney entrance, what can I do?

Tags: insulation, asbestos, chimney, mdf, flue

We get a significant draft down the chimney of our Victorian house. I'd like to put some sort of temporary insulation in there, such as a "chimney sheep" product.

However, the entrance to our chimney is partially blocked by some sort of fibreboard. I don't understand why this is, or how to stop the draft. Is the fibreboard here normal? Is it likely to be asbestos? can I cut it out of the chimney or is that likely to cause further problems?

[image: chimney from below]

[Further context for the image: this shows our chimney from underneath. The fibreboard is visible as the paint has partially peeled away on it. The actual chimney cavity has some plastic bags in, these were taped in place, so you can see some silver tape in place. The chimney has recently been capped and vented.]

Comment: Are the sides the same material?  I think you should strip all that stuff out and see what you really have in there. then decide how to fix it right.

Comment: Do you actually use the fireplace, or plan to in the future? If not, why not have a professional safely decommission it?

Comment: Thanks for your question Armand. I'd rather be able to use the fireplace in the future.

@Jack The Sides are not the same material. I agree that I'd like to strip it out. Just worried it is asbestos.

Comment: @Arthur  We can't tell if it's asbestos and you can't tell unless it's been tested. Wet it down, remove and bag it. Asbestos problems occur after long exposure to it, not an isolated incident such as removing a small piece. Where a mask.